# Composer rest server api endpoint documentation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am working on web app which will consume apis generated from composer rest server. Is there any document regarding the api endpoints of composer rest server, so that I can code my http get and post calls. I mainly want it to complete my multi user story at UI end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the swagger.json endpoint?

I think it will give you the information that you are looking for.

http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json

**Extra Information**
When run in Multi-user mode the /wallet endpoints should also appear in the swagger.json (just tested using OAuth2.0 tutorial).  Short extract follows:

```
{  
"swagger":"2.0",
"info":{  
  "version":"1.0.0",
  "title":"LoopBack Application"
},
"basePath":"/api",
"paths":{  
  "/wallet":{  
     "get":{  
        "tags":[  
           "Wallet"
        ],
        "summary":"Get all of the business network cards in the wallet",
        "operationId":"Card.getAllCards",
        "parameters":[  
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Its not showing any info regarding wallet management endpoints. FYI I am running rest server in multiuser mode.